# NGINX SSL Connection Error

Tags: nginx, ssl

I've added an SSL certificate to my server. (Nginx running passenger & Rails).

I created a CSR, uploaded to GoDaddy, downloaded the keys. Inside /srv/ssl I have

```
www.mydomain.com.crt
www.mydomain.com.key
```

My nginx Version:

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.2.6
built by gcc 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-cc-opt=-Wno-error --with-pcre=/tmp/root-passenger-27798/pcre-8.31 --add-module=/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/nginx
```

I added this to my nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate    /srv/ssl/www.mydomain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /srv/ssl/www.mydomain.com.key;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Besides the two ssl lines and the port being on 443 instead of 80, the server block is identical to the one above it which serves the regular http.

When I use

listen 443 ssl;
and uncomment this:

#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

```
#    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
```

Then I get an SSL expired warning.

When I re-comment those and just use

```
listen 443 ssl;
```

Then I get an error but, when I visit

https://www.mydomain.com/login with a www, I get a green lock in Chrome but a 404. Does this mean I have SSL configured for "www" but not the non-www?

Answer (score 1):

Your `server_name` is set to `localhost`. You have to put your domain name there (www.domain.com, if your cert has www. prefix), so that nginx can select the proper vhost during SSL negotiation.